# How to create seeds.rb array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I'd like to populate the Department table using the seeds.rb file.  I've created only two columns in the table.  There are three more created by rails (id, created_at, updated_at).

When I run `rake db:seed`, I get the following error:

> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 0..1)

Here's what the seeds.rb file looks like:

```
departments = Department.create([{ depttitle: 'dept 1' }, { deptdescription: 'this is the first dept' }],
[{ depttitle: 'dept 2' }, { deptdescription: 'this is the second dept' }],
[{ depttitle: 'dept 3' }, { deptdescription: 'this is the third dept' }])
```

Is the issue with how I've created the array or something else?

Comment: Each record should be a single hash, with each attribute define with a key-value pair. Not an array of hashes consisting of one key-value pair each. You should look up documentation and examples for `create` method of `ActiveRecord::Base`

Comment: Does each record get its own line then?  Do you overwrite departments each time?  Or do you even need the departments variable? An example would be great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason it didn't work is that you actually passed three arrays with two hashes in each of them.

Pass a single array to the `#create` method with a single hash for each record you want to create. 
For example:

```
Department.create([{ deptitle: 'dept 1', deptdescription: 'this is the first dept' },
                   { depttitle: 'dept 2', deptdescription: 'this is the second dept' }])
```

But instead of 'creating an array' you could use a simple loop to create Department records.

```
10.times do |x|
  Department.create({deptitle: "dept #{x}", deptdescription: "this is the #{x} department"})
end
```

In my opinion it looks cleaner, takes less place and it is easier to change number of seed records if you need to.

To create a numeral from a number (for "this is the Xst dept" sentence) you could use a [humanize](https://github.com/radar/humanize) gem.

Answer (score 1):

The way we do it is as follows:

```
departments = [
   {depttitle: "Title", deptdescription: "description"},
   {depttitle: "Title2", deptdescription: "description2"},
   {depttitle: "Title3", deptdesctiption: "description3"}
]
```

You can then loop through them like this:

```
departments.each do |department|
   Department.create department
end
```

`@Sebastian Brych`'s answer is right though - you're passing arrays for each new record when you should pass a single array with multiple hashes.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your records separately as shown below.

```
Department.create(depttitle: 'dept 1' , deptdescription: 'this is the    first dept')
Department.create(depttitle: 'dept 2' , deptdescription: 'this is the second dept')
```